# What would it take to actually move the Earth using a lever?

Tags: science-based, planets

Archimedes claimed that he would lift the Earth if he could find a suitable place outside it, with his knowledge of mechanics.

So, my question is: What kind of set-up (e.g. how large lever or how massive support to stand etc.) would Archimedes require to carry out this project? And how long he would have to keep pursuing (assume that he is alone doing all these) to move the Earth by a fair amount?

Comment: You mean doing something like this but with moar science ? http://www.blogcdn.com/www.urlesque.com/media/2010/10/1-1287973508.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ted-Ed actually did a video on levers. You can see it (fast-forwarded to the answer of this very question) [here](https://youtu.be/YlYEi0PgG1g?t=3m31s)!

Their length of a lever around *quadrillion light-years*, for a lever which uses the moon as a fulcrum, is really infeasible. By infeasible, I mean it has multiple problems. The first is simply getting that much material without it bending, twisting, or snapping. The second is getting a material that has the strength needed to act as a fulcrum. The third is getting enough gravity on the Archimedes end of things so he can exert that force on that lever.

As far as I can tell, there is no material that would be that strong. So, while lifting the earth with a large enough lever is possible, making that large lever is not. Sorry, Archie!

Answer (score 1):

Define "fair amount".

You move the Earth using a lever every time you stand up.  [Newton's 3rd law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion) says you must be.  The combined center of mass of you and the Earth will not move but you both gain exactly the same potential energy as your own centers of mass move apart.  It's the difference in mass that accounts for the difference in movement.  You do move the Earth.  The only issue is, by how much?

Archimedes said he needed a lever, a fulcrum, and a place to stand.  Your legs are the lever.  Your knees are the fulcrum.  Earth itself is the place to stand. You're really getting your leverage (mechanical advantage) because of where your muscles tendon attaches to bone.

Since you're not as massive as the Earth you do most of the moving.  Just not all of it.  Putting on weight would let you move the Earth more.  So would having more leverage (longer legs).

Whatever your "fair amount" is there exists some combination of body weight and length of legs that will satisfy it.

Not that other issues won't arise.  Even if your body could function with these modifications eventually you're going to need some big feet or you'll just kick thru the Earth's crust into the mantle.  Earth is like a big ball of hot mud.  You can't just poke it in one place if you're going to move it significantly.